# Reading in File to String

Tags: c

I'm trying to read the contents of a file into a string, and am having trouble with allocating memory for the string. I am reading in the file line by line, b/c I want to skip the first two lines.

```
int counter=1;
char *myhtml;
myhtml=calloc(1,10);

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) 
{
    if (counter>2)
    {
        //printf("%s",line);
        myhtml=realloc(myhtml,sizeof(char)*strlen(line));
        strcat(myhtml,line);                        
    }
    counter++;
}
```

How would I go about reallocating memory for this kind of function?

Comment: It might be worth rereading carefully the documentation for `realloc()`. In particular, it doesn't *increase* the allocated size of a memory block, it *sets* the new size to whatever you ask for.

Comment: Also, think about what would happen if `realloc` fails and return `NULL`, you will then loose the original pointer if you reassign to the pointer you reallocate.

Comment: The way that you are using `strcat` reminds me of this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Comment: post definition of `line, len` and the values `line, len` were initialized with.

Comment: Use something like `realloc(myhtml, strlen(myhtml) + strlen(line) + 1);`

Comment: I'd call fstat on the file and allocate the memory and read the file in one go,

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're just reading in a file, you could just allocate the whole space for the file at once like:

```
struct stat statbuf;
stat("testfile", &statbuf);
char *myhtml = calloc(1,statbuf.st_size);
```

and maybe free the rest after you're done reading in.
Which is way cheaper because malloc is pretty expensive

Comment: To make a C string out of the contents, add 1 to the length for the terminating `'\0'`.  (And hope there are no `'\0'` characters in the file contents...)  Also check your return values.  Oh, use `fstat()` on the file descriptor after you open the file since the file has to be open anyway.

Answer (score 0):

there are several 'problems' with the posted code.

Rather than my detailing each problem.  just compare the posted code with the following

The following code eliminates those 'problems' and is faster as 'counter' is not being tested nor incremented, nor is 'counter' cluttering the stack.

```
char *myhtml = NULL; // the accumulated lines
char *line = NULL;   // the current line
int len;             // set by the readline() function

// read and discard first two lines
getline(&line, &len, fp);
free(line);
line = NULL;
getline(&line, &len, fp);
free(line);
line = NULL;

while ((getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
    char *temp = NULL; // so do not lose pointer to already allocated memory
    if( NULL ==(temp=realloc(myhtml,strlen(myhtml)+len+1) ) ) )
    { // realloc failed
        perror( "realloc failed");
        free( myhtml ); // cleanup
        free( line );   // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, realloc successful

    myhtml = temp;
    strcat(myhtml,line);
    free(line); // getline() performs a hidden malloc(), so have to free())
    line = NULL;  // reset for next iteration
}
```